# Are there difference about "and" and "or" between active sentence and passive sentence?

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions

> No creature has received more praise **and** abuse than the common garden snail.

> No creature has been praised **or** abused more often than the common garden snail.

It is said that these two sentences are the same. But I feel that we should replace **or** with **and** in the second sentence. I am confusing about using **or** in the second sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. No creature has received more praise and abuse than the common garden snail.

> 2. No creature has been praised or abused more often than the common garden snail.

The two examples do not mean the same; *and* sums up the frequency of praise and of abuse, but *or* does not.

Example 2 means the snail has experienced both types of treatments, counted separately, more than any other creature.

Replacing *or* with *and* in example 2 should make it mean about the same as example 1 does.

Comment: You should add a hypothetical [by x] after praised and abused as a learner might not realize that.